# How can I add a divider between two elements in a responsive navbar

Tags: html, css

I am trying to accomplish the following navbar that scales with the window size. I want each link item to take up 33% of the bar. Everything is working except the fact that I am unable to add a divider `|` that is centered between the link items.

```
                Link1          |         link2          |           link3
```

This is what I have so far:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have tried playing around with the `:before { content: " | "; }` but that puts the divider directly next to the text link1 and I would like the divider to be exactly in the middle between link1 and link2, and link2 and link3 without removing the position of either link element.

Comment: you can simply do it like this : <nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">link 1</a></li>
<li>|</li>
    <li><a href="#section2">link 2</a></li>
<li>|</li>
    <li><a href="#section3">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want each link to take `33%` of the width then you need to define it because `space-around` will not do this unless all your links will have the same width. Then you can add a gradient for the dividers

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  padding: 10px;
  --s: 2px; /* thickness */
  /* adjust the 40% to control the height */
  background:
    linear-gradient(90deg,red var(--s),#0000 0) repeat-x content-box
    calc(-1*var(--s)) 50%/calc((100% + var(--s))/3) 40%;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0;
}
ul li {
  flex: 1; /* equal width */
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">a long link</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much. This is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `border-right`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li{
  flex: auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

ul li:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: solid red 1px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: This is a really nice solution as well, I was unable to use grid for this assignment otherwise I'd use your solution.

Comment: Hello! The `grid` is only used for centering )) You can replace it for example with `ul li{ display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; }`

Answer (score 0):

If you can't or don't want to include actual (HTML-)content, you could give the `li`'s a full width and a relative position. After that, you can position a visual element using ::before and ::after anywhere inside that `li`.

I've made a crude example based of your code.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

li:not(:first-child)::before {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  left: -.5px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: auto;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section2">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#section3">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do it like this :

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#section1">link 1</a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="#section2">link 2</a></li>
    <li>|</li>
    <li><a href="#section3">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

If you need more control, you can add a span (`<li>|</li> -> <li><span></span></li>`) and style your element has you want.